# Have installed “Command line” but whenever i try to build and run my program terminal says “No such file or directory”

Tags: terminal, command-line, xcode

[image]

I have tried to build and run my project through CodeLite.

I have installed Command Line but somehow it doesn't work.

It says "no such file or directory"

but whenever I ask it to look for gcc, it tells me that i have it in my Mac.

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: To improve your question, copy all the text from the terminal and paste it as "code" rather than taking a screenshot, that way it is easier to copy and edit commands so they become correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the terminal incorrectly. Put double quotes around the path:

```
cd "/Users/Kathieen Ashley/Documents/mytest/testproject2/Debug"
## new line!
./testproject2
```

Don't use `&&`, they do not do what you think they do.

If you want to know more, have a look at [Bash Guide for Beginners](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html).

To elaborate a bit more on your questions:

> I have installed Command Line but somehow it doesn't work.

It seems to work just as intended, but maybe not as you intended.

> It says "no such file or directory"

`cd`, a command called ‘change directory’, says that there is no such directory or file as `/Users/Kathieen`, which is correct since your user folder seems to be
`/Users/Kathieen Ashley` (note the space followed by an additional word)

> but whenever I ask it to look for gcc, it tells me that I have it in my Mac.

That is correct, gcc is installed correctly.

Comment: No need to avoid `&&` in this case, they work fine with this command providing the path was quoted correctly, not sure why you're suggesting to not use `&&`?

Comment: @grgarside To easy to get into "unknown" states with `&&` if you are not comfortable with Bash in my opinion (i.e. did I or did I not change directory? Or a compiler returning `0` even though failing and messing up a build directory). The question indicated a bit of unfamiliarity with the command line, therefore I'd recommend OP not to use `&&` but rather do one command per line.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your home folder containts a space character which is taken as a separator by the shell. That's why it says `cd: /Users/Kathieen: No such file or directory`.

Try

```
cd /Users/Kathieen\ Ashley/Documents/mytest/testproject2/Debug && ./testproject2
```

or as two commands (better for a lot of reasons)

```
cd /Users/Kathieen\ Ashley/Documents/mytest/testproject2/Debug
./testproject2
```